# Комментарии и текст кракозябрами после преобразования проекта в Maven

Tags: java, кодировка, maven

Собственно был проект. После преобразования в maven стал весь вида:

```
//�������� ���������� ������� � ��, ������� ������ �������
//������� ����, ��� ���� ��������� (� �� � ��������� ��� ����� ��������)
public JButton bInsert = new JButton("��������");
public JButton bUpdate = new JButton("��������");
public JButton bDelete = new JButton("�������");
/**
* ������ ��� ���������� ������� �� ������ ActionListener
```

Window -> Preferences -> Workspace и в проекте Проект -> Properties стоит text file encoding Cp1251.
Как не меняй, хоть UTF8, все равно как по коду вверху.
Ничего не понимаю...

Comment: попробуйте добавить в пом такое проперти :
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

Comment: Увы, это не помогло. Пришлось прогнать все файлы через конвертер в UTF-8.